# BCP with UTF8 SQLserver 2016

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have SQL Server 2016 on Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. When I tried to do BCP export with UTF-8 option, I get this error. Any idea how to solve this? I have read that SQL Server 2014 onward support UTF.

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0] This version of SQL Server Native Client does not support UTF-8 encoding (code page 65001)

I used the following command to execute BCP:

```
bcp "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)" queryout "C:\USERS\Direcotry\TEST\TestData.csv" -t"|" -c -C 65001 -r 0x0A -T -S ServerName
```

Comment: According to [support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq), `bcp` had code page 65001 added in SQL Server 2014 SP (though according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it was 2016) Either way, if you are using 2016 it will support UTF8. Are you are using 2016?

Comment: On a different note, Why a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`, and why a `NOLOCK` (you do understand what `NOLOCK` does, correct)?

Answer (score 0):

can you try running the following command?

```
bcp -v
```

Verify it is at least a SQL Server 2016 bcp exe version.

I was having the same error and it turned out that our bcp was an exe version from 2012.
Also make sure your executing database is in 2016 compatibility mode.