# SQL server using Native Client 10.0 error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-native-client

I need to run a BCP export from a db for an external client. The stored proc is pre-written. When I try and output the file to csv, I get this error

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]This version of SQL
> Server Native Client does not support UTF-8 encoding (code page 65001)

SQL Server 2016 running at compatibility 130.

Drivers 10.0,11.0,13,18 are all installed on the server.
I've tried reinstalling Driver 11.0
I've tried disabling 10.0 in SQL server management console
Both 10 and 11 Drivers seems to be available in the registry

It may be my misunderstanding of how drivers work but I thought SQL Server 2016 would need to use 11.0 by default.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check bcp version as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873816/bcp-with-utf8-sqlserver-2016.  It does sound like it's an older version of BCP (which, ultimately, I think is going to expect to use a set version of the SQL client ...... I'll stand corrected if I'm wrong, though)

Comment: SNAC10.0 is obsolete - you should be using OLE-DB or ODBC instead, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I find it hard to believe you installed SQLNCLI 13 and 18, considering that the last release was 11, which (as already mentioned) is deprecated (as of SQL Server 2012) and doesn't technically support anything after 2014.

Comment: @Craig - Thanks for that. It does look as though it may be an old version of BCP Version: 10.50.6560.0. I've tried to upgrade it by installing the latest version but it's still showing that older version for some reason, but at least I may be heading in the right direction now. Many thanks.